# How to make MySQL container run in the background when configured in docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I've created the `docker-compose.yml` file below to create a container based on Ruby image and a container based on MySQL image. When I execute `docker-compose up`, the MySQL container seems to be created correctly, however it is not run in the background. How can I configure it to do so using the `docker-compose.yml` file?

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/rails.dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - .:/var/www
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - 'mysql'
    networks:
      - ddoc-network


  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'SOMETHING'
    networks:
      - ddoc-network


networks:
  ddoc-network:
    driver: bridge
```

rails.dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

MAINTAINER Juliano Nunes

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

ADD Gemfile /var/www/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /var/www/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /var/www

CMD ['bundle', 'exec', 'rails', 'server', '-b', '0.0.0.0']
```

[image: CMD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `docker-compose up -d` to run your containers in detached mode.

Check `docker-compose up --help` for more info.